# Comparing two cells and show both of them when it is not equal

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have a table in EXCEL that looks like this:

```
ATTRIBUTE_IN_1|TYPE_IN_1|ATTRIBUTE_IN_2 |TYPE_IN_2      |
________________________________________________________
advance       |String   | accounts      |decimal(20,10) |
education     |String   | Job_category  |String         |
date of birth |date     | advance       |decimal(20,10) |
```

and etc.

I want to compare `TYPE_IN_1` and `TYPE_IN_2` (2nd and 4th columns) for equal values in `ATTRIBUTE_IN_1` and `ATTRIBUTE_IN_2` (1st and 3rd columns).

In the result I want to see values, when `ATTRIBUTE_IN_1` and `ATTRIBUTE_IN_2` have equal value, but `TYPE_IN_1` and `TYPE_IN_2` (2nd and 4th columns) have unequal values.

For that example in result I want to see:

```
ATTRIBUTE_IN_1|TYPE_IN_1|ATTRIBUTE_IN_2 |TYPE_IN_2      |
_______________________________________________________
advance       |String   | advance       |decimal(20,10) |
```

What formula can i use in MS EXCEL for solving this problem?

Comment: Easy in SQL, hard in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel doesn't really lend itself to this type of question. You can cobble something together, perhaps along these lines (for attribute 1):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$10,INT(SMALL(IF(($A$2:$A$10=TRANSPOSE($C$2:$C$10))*($B$2:$B$10<>TRANSPOSE($D$2:$D$10)),
ROWS($A$2:$A$10)*(ROW($A$2:$A$10)-ROW($A$2))+TRANSPOSE(ROW($A$2:$A$10)-ROW($A$2))),ROW(1:1))/ROWS($A$2:$A$10))+1),"")
```

This sets up a 2D array where the rows are the attribute 1's and the columns are the attribute 2's. The array elements where there is a conflict are set to 1. The rest of the formula is to get the corresponding values out in row/column order.

For type 1:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$10,INT(SMALL(IF(($A$2:$A$10=TRANSPOSE($C$2:$C$10))*($B$2:$B$10<>TRANSPOSE($D$2:$D$10)),
ROWS($A$2:$A$10)*(ROW($A$2:$A$10)-ROW($A$2))+TRANSPOSE(ROW($A$2:$A$10)-ROW($A$2))),ROW(1:1))/ROWS($A$2:$A$10))+1),"")
```

For type 2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$10,MOD(SMALL(IF(($A$2:$A$10=TRANSPOSE($C$2:$C$10))*($B$2:$B$10<>TRANSPOSE($D$2:$D$10)),
ROWS($A$2:$A$10)*(ROW($A$2:$A$10)-ROW($A$2))+TRANSPOSE(ROW($A$2:$A$10)-ROW($A$2))),ROW(1:1)),ROWS($A$2:$A$10))+1),"")
```

[image]

It's interesting to compare this with the SQL for doing the same thing e.g. in SQLite:

```
.mode csv
.import book2.csv test1
select a.attribute_in_1,a.type_in_1,b.type_in_2
from
test1 a inner join test1 b
on a.attribute_in_1=b.attribute_in_2 and a.type_in_1<>b.type_in_2;
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. Not recommended for large tables, but as you say, it does work.